# Visual Studios 2013 with VM on 12" mac1.3GHz Dual-Core Intel Core M

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, mac, vmware

I'm a non mac user. But I would like to buy the latest mac 12" 1.3GHz Dual-Core Intel Core M. But I need Visual Studios 2013 the requirements are 1.6 GHz or faster processor.
Can this be install in VM and work? Thank you in advance.

Comment: There are several latest Macs - I thin k you mean MacBook. As noted on reviews it is slower than MacBook Air let alone MacBook Pro. As for VS - well I'll bet VS2015 will need more CPU and you will upgrade to that before you upgrade the Mac. As for install yes it will probably install - the question is how well it will run and MS are suggesting not well but depends on how complex your builds are. I think if not pure web based you need more powerful machines (I end up with desktops for this reason)

Comment: Yes, and your absolutely right not doing web on vs. Keeping the desktops it is. Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you are talking about the latest MacBook and not Air or Pro?

VS will probably install and maybe even start, but the MacBook(without suffix) was never invented to be for developers, indeed it isn't even meant to complete any complicated tasks, but only Web and Office, which means that you won't be able to properly work with it.

I can only recommend buying a MacBook Pro which even starts cheaper at 1099$ with a 2.5 Ghz Dual-Core processor.

Comment: Thank you for your recommendation, will keep it in consideration.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to really know for your workload is to buy it and try it with your projects. In the U.S. and EU, there's a 14 day return policy which should be enough time to test it out. It's got a fast SSD and w/ 8GB of RAM it might be good enough. It has a turbo-burst speed of 2.6Ghz so there are a lot of performance variables in play.